# Sort array based on another array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to sort the second array($array2)  based on first array($field['choices'])

```
$field_name = "field_52f8fcdd21cb6";
$field = get_field_object($field_name);

foreach( $field['choices'] as $k=>$v) {
    echo $k."==".$v."<br>";
}
```

The above code gives me the following output

```
Gyana Yagna==Gyana Yagna
Festival==Festival
Retreat==Retreat
Performance==Performance
Swaranjali==Swaranjali
```

Now the second array starts

```
echo "<br><br><br>";
$array2 = array("Gyana Yagna","Gyana Yagna","Gyana Yagna","Retreat","Festival","Festival");

foreach( $array2 as $k=>$v)
{
    if(in_array($v,$field['choices']))
    {
        echo $array2[$k]."<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $array2[$k+1]."<br>";
    }
}
```

Desired output should be

```
Gyana Yagna
Gyana Yagna
Gyana Yagna
Festival
Festival
Retreat
```

Whereas I am getting the following output

```
Gyana Yagna
Gyana Yagna
Gyana Yagna
Retreat
Festival
Festival
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Output is wrong because you are looping over the 2nd array hence $array2[3], is returning $v = "Retreat" which is then used by in_array($v,$field['choices']) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution based on my comment:

```
$field['choices']= array('Gyana Yagna', 'Festival', 'Retreat');


echo "<br><br><br>";
$array2 = array("Gyana Yagna","Gyana Yagna","Gyana Yagna","Retreat","Festival","Festival");

foreach( $field['choices'] as $k=>$v)
{
foreach($array2 as $k2=>$v2){
    if($v==$v2)
      {
          echo $array2[$k2]."<br>";
      }
}

}
```

And Output is same as your desired output.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like charm. Thanks once again.